# at nodejs.org, is the linux tar file going to work on cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin

I need to get node.js for a program I'm installing in Cygwin, and I'm wondering if the Linux download at nodejs.org is going to work, or does something like this for Cygwin need to be built from source? I tried downloading the linux tarball and incorporating into the installation script for Oppia (the program I'm installing) and it doesn't work, but I don't know enough about this to know what's wrong.

Comment: I suppose node.js on cygwin is not really supported. I worked with node.js under cygwin, installed with Windows installer. There are some problems, especially when there are dependencies on paths (`/cygdrive/c/...`). I haven't tried to build from source, but asked the guys on the node.js google group a similar question, but they just said: not supported. So probably it's better to write those unbelievable ugly .bat/.cmd scripts and use the DOS shell commands when working with Windows (which I hate so much). I tried to use PowerShell, but it was no improvement, it's odd.

Comment: Thank you. I see other places that suggest node.js is not supported on Cygwin. Can you post your answer as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose node.js on cygwin is not really supported. I worked with node.js under cygwin, installed with Windows installer. There are some problems, especially when there are dependencies on paths (`/cygdrive/c/...`). I haven't tried to build from source, but asked the guys on the node.js google group a similar question, but they just said: not supported.

So probably it's better to write those unbelievable ugly .bat/.cmd scripts and use the DOS shell commands when working with Windows (which I hate so much). I tried to use PowerShell, but it was no improvement, it's odd compared to bash.